# Need to get max value from database table

Tags: mysql, max

I'm trying to get max value from database but it doesnt work for me. That i did wrong whith it?

```
  $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 $query_for_com = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM Comments";
    $mysql_query5= mysqli_query($con,$query_for_com);
    while ($query_row_com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysql_query5)) {
    echo $id_for = $query_row_com['Id'];
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @StoviRyžasStotelėje your query is correct however the fetch part is not you may need to add an alias as `SELECT MAX(id) as max_id` and finally `$id_for = $query_row_com['max_id'];` , also using aggregate function without group by always returns one row and hence you may not need to do a loop rather can fetch the record straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$query_for_com = "SELECT id FROM Comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: it works. if you dont mind can you tell me why it didnt worked my way?